# Why are controllers in ASP.NET mvc RC2 partial classes and all the action methods are virtual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have build a production system using ASP.NET MVC 1 and am now playing and preparing a talk on the second installment.

One peculiar thing that I can't comprehend is why all **controllers** and **action** methods have gone **partial** and **virtual**.

This question will surely pop-up at the Q&A round and I have no answer to it. So please if somebody knows what this has been done please share your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are declared partial for the purpose of extensibility.

Every group of controller actions (for a single controller) can for example be contained in a separate file. This can improve maintainability of your source code.

A nice example of how the partial classes are used is in the Telerik MVC Extensions example project.

Comment: +1 for grouping controller actions.  Hadn't thought of it that way before.

Answer (score 1):

They had not (AFAIK). Are you maybe using T4MVC (which converts controllers to partials and actions to virtuals)?

Edit: ouch. I have just remembered that I have still the RC1. Please ignore my answer if this is issue on RC2.

Cheers!